# Jasmine - How to write a test for event.target.id

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a function like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit-element', App.books.elementClickHandler);

function elementClickHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if(event.target.id == 'waitlist-button'){
    $('#state-modal-title').html('Waitlist');
  }else{
    $('#state-modal-title').html('Comment');
  }
}
```

I wonder how can I simulate the event parameter so that I can have event.target.id when I write the unit tests for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm the stupid guy who will ask the question like this. The answer is pretty simple. You can just create a trigger event in beforeEach block to determine which button got clicked.